# Склонение слова "некий"

Tags: склонение, прилагательные

Задумался: как правильно образовать родительный падеж от слова "некий":
**некого** или **некоего**?

Comment: А Вы разве не женщина? "Задумал**ся**...

Comment: Fuchoin Kazuki — образ виртуальный, у него не смена пола, а смена рода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово книжного стиля. В мужском роде формы без вариантов. В женском варианты возможны. 
не́кий, не́кое, не́коего, не́коему, не́ким, о не́коем, не́кая, не́коей и не́кой, не́кую, о не́коей и о не́кой, мн. не́кие, не́ких
Орфографический словарь, 2004

Comment: А теперь я одновременно с Вами ...

Answer (score 3):

В родительном падеже слово **некий** имеет форму **некоего** (не путать с отрицательным местоимением *некого*).

Answer (score 1):

Зализняк, 1980 г. Если пробежаться по современным словарям, ситуация, похоже, не изменилась.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Большой толковый словарь

НЕКИЙ, некоего, м.; НЕКАЯ, некоей и некой, ж.; НЕКОЕ, некоего, ср.; мн.: некие, некоих и неких; местоим. прил.
1.
=Некоторый (1-2 зн.). С некоего момента началась реакция. Некие группировки образовали фракцию. Была в нём некая странность.
2. (в сочет. с фамилией, именем).
Какой-то (о ком-л., точно не известном). Спросите некоего Иванова. Билеты у некоего Сидорова.